# Alternative to billing agreements that aren't deprecated?

Tags: paypal

We are a online donation SaaS provider for non-profits. Non-profits are able to integrate their accounts into our platform to enable their donors to donate via their PayPal accounts. Donors can also save their PayPal account to use it at any point later (for recurring gifts or just for convenience). This structure requires us to have a way for users to save their PayPal accounts to our system and allow us to bill arbitrary amounts to their accounts at any point (similar to tokenizing a credit card).

We are currently able to accomplish this with billing agreements provided by the NVP API. However, as this API is deprecated our customers must manually phone PayPal to enable "reference transactions" to enable support for saving PayPal acounts.

Is there a way for us to accomplish a similar task with the new APIs?

I was doing research on alternatives a while back and came across a new type of [billing agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#billing-agreements) that may have worked, but it looks this was also deprecated recently in favor of subscriptions which as far as I can tell, can't do what I need them to do (tokenizing an account and billing it whenever I want).

Answer (score 1):

Billing agreements always have been, and still are, used for both reference transactions and subscriptions (edit: the newest subscriptions API doesn't use billing agreements anymore: only products, billing plans, and subscriptions themselves).

The feature you wish to accomplish always has, and still does, require reference transactions -- which must be enabled on the account.

Enabling reference transactions always has, and still does, require business approval by a PayPal account manager, or their https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us support

The only publicly-available documentation for using reference transaction is via Classic APIs, like NVP. If approved for reference transactions PayPal might offer instructions for using the feature with a newer API, such as "v2 vault" (*not* the old v1 vault--which is not useful)